# How do I find a variable within a string in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have a variable "test".

```
test = "stranger"

print(test)

--> stranger

longtest = "He's not a stranger"

i,j = string.find(longtest,test)

--> Invalid capture index
```

How do I pass the value of the variable into test?

Comment: seems to work just fine when i try it on https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo . i think that error happens on a different line

Comment: Can confirm that it works perfectly well. There's no error in that code.

Comment: Use `string.find(longtest,test,1,true)` instead of `string.find(longtest,test)`

Comment: Your piece of code is correct. I guess you have problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Just in case, I thought it was worth me mentioning that `string.find` returns the start and end index of "test", not true/false?